# background color problem in an access form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form containing a textbox "Text20". I have put some code in the OnCurrent event of the form:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Current()
Text20.BackColor = vbRed
End Sub
```

It does nothing when I display the form whereas it should color my textbox. Do you see why ?

Thank you

Comment: `Text20` means you presumably have at least 19 other textboxes on your form. Are you sure `Text20` is visible? Your code looks correct.

Comment: Does the code run? Add a breakpoint by clicking the line and pressing F9.

Comment: hum it works with all versions of access except 2010

Comment: It work for me in 2010. Try a decompile and / or compact & repair.

Comment: thank you Remou it was the compact & repair I'm not familiar with Access I didn't know ;)

Comment: `Me!Text20.BackColor = vbRed` or `Me.Text20.BackColor = vbRed` would be better code, though leaving out the parent should not cause the code not to run. You DO understand, though, that the background color is being set every time the form arrives on a new record, and if you don't have the properties for the control set appropriately, you won't see anything (e.g., if you have it set to transparent or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no reason to do this in the code behind. Just right click the control, select conditional formatting and apply the formatting and give it a condition and a format.

No code required.

[image]

In fact, the code you included in your example would re-set that every time the form changes records, which is overkill anyway.

Better yet. Why not just set the color in the property sheet for the control?

[image]